# mongoengine QuerySet.to_json doesn't call Document.to_json

Tags: python, json, mongodb, mongoengine

I have over-ridden my to_json method on Foo, a subclass of mongoengine Document. When I call Foo.objects().to_json(), my override is not used. Is there a way to ensure that documents are serialised for presentation without repeating myself?

`class Foo(Document):
    presentation_field = StringField(required=True, unique=True)
    technical_field = StringField(required=True, unique=True)`

```
def to_json(self):
    data = self.to_mongo()
    data.pop('technical_field')
    return bson.json_util.dumps(data)
```

foos = Foo.objects()
    for foo in foos:
        print foo.to_json() #override is used!!!!
    print foos.to_json() # override is ignored :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a feature rather than a bug. The proper way to do this is Foo.objects().only('presentation_field') for column filtering.